How can I reward a good *question* (not an answer) with a bounty?
The title says it all. If I would like to reward a question, how do I do it? Screen shots of the process would be appreciated.

It doesn't seem possible.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/211127

A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. This feature
  was designed to motivate answerers, and help questions get the answers
  they deserve.

So it's intended to encourage answers, not questions.

Hey Igor, shame. Because, true, it makes no sense to offer a bounty for a question upfront, but I still hold there should be a way to reward outstanding questions, not just answers. Since I can only upvote once, worth 5 rep, this is somewhat limiting. Thanks for the response and the link, though.
